# How to target and affect dom element in js (noobie)

Tags: javascript

so long story short,

I'm testing something out, a simple rollover and i notice that for example, if i use this

```
css:
#box{ width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#F00;}

html:
<div id="box" class="boxClass">this is sample text</div>


Js:
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeBox(){
    //box.style.backgroundColor = "#1896fa";    
    box.style.backgroundColor = "#1896fa";

}

box.onmouseover = changeBox;
```

it works, simple as can be. simple mouseover, simple js...simple. Mouse rolls over and changes from red to bue...good, but then when i try to target the same div via

```
var box = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

or

```
getElementsByClassName("boxClass");
```

nothing happens. my ? is why?

reason im asking is because, i have a simple image gallery and wanted to implement gallery wide rollovers but didnt want to write them for EVERY image.

was trying to somehow group them all together via tagName("img") or ClassName("boxClass")

but to no avail. i know older browsers dont support some of these but i looked it up and saw all modern browsers sans Ie are a go. what am i missing?

any tips help direction is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` returns an Array.

Comment: @rekire it returns a `NodeList` not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) function which returns a single element, the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) function returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) of DOM elements (which is normal as you could have multiple elements with this tag). So if you want to change the background color to all `<div>` elements in the DOM you will have to first loop through the elements of this collection.

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1896fa"; 
}
```

Same remark stands true for the [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) function.

Comment: Hehe I wrote the answer in the same second as a comment.

Comment: it returns a `NodeList` not an array. Also the loop is redundant since you are just accessing the first item in all iterations.

Comment: This code is still not correct.  You need to set `box=boxes[i]` or just refer to `boxes[i]` inside the loop, not just in the initialization code for the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00, why? Seems to work great as seen in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NUYV2/

Comment: Your loop is only operating on the first element in the list.  If there is more than one, it never gets to the other ones.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NUYV2/1/.  This is how it should be: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CfP7H/.

Comment: @jfriend00, you are correct. Thanks for pointing this out. Answer updated once again to take it into account.

Comment: thanks for answering all of u. i was looking at the code you guys have provided and, guess its my fault for not asking a better formed question. This code bit overall, works,i have a version of this written and the problem is that, like the one above,this targets all the divs at the same time, what i originally wanted/needed help with was to somehow group them (like the code u provided) but still keep it separate. so mouseover on div 1 gives one result, over div 2 another etc...i just didnt want to write rollover/out funcitons for ALL the images and their parent divs. hope its not confusing.